# Constant declaration - language difference?

Tags: c++, c

The following snippet of code is completely valid in C++ (at least gets compiled):

**my_file.cxx:**

```
static const int MY_CONST_ONE = 1;
static const int MY_CONST_TWO = MY_CONST_ONE;
```

On the other hand, compilation of exactly the same code in C fails with the error message (http://ideone.com/erBkm9):

```
my_file.c:2:1: error: initializer element is not constant
```

**my_file.c:**

```
static const int MY_CONST_ONE = 1;
static const int MY_CONST_TWO = MY_CONST_ONE;
```

What is the reason? Is it something compiler-specific or some known C vs C++ difference?

Comment: Your compiler already did the work. Post it's result, so we don't have to do the work again.

Comment: @AlokSave, this question is a lot simpler and easier to understand than the one you linked. I'd recommend keeping it.

Comment: @MarkRansom: But it is a duplicate. The marked duplicate answers exactly what is being asked here and more. What does *simpler and easier* to understand have to do with it? If at all you can go ahead do the reverse marking of duplicates, but I don't think it would do any justice to the content in the other Q.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically, `const` variables in C are not considered compile-time constants. Places where compile-time constants are needed can thus *not* get their values from `const` variables.

Comment: Thanks! It makes perfect sense considering the compilation error that I get.